# Cannot implicitly convert type "int" to "bool"

Tags: c#, md5, implicit-conversion

This my function

```
public string getMD5hash(string input)
{
    //create a new instance of MD5 object
    MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create(); 
    //convert the input value to byte array
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; data.Length -1 ; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

I get an error in `data.Length` that cannot implicitly convert type "int" to "bool"

Comment: Any reason why you are using MD5?  Just curious as it is outdated and shouldn't be used for anything other than fall back scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `for` loop and make the second clause a `bool`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
}
```

Note the change `i < data.Length`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= data.Length-1; i++) { ... }
```

or equivalent:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the for loop.  The second term needs to be a condition.  What's there will evaluate to an integer.  Hence the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You want this for statement.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
```

You had `data.Length-1` as the termination condition. That is in fact an integer, and the termination condition needs to be a boolean.

Notice that you could also use this form of the loop, which is simpler and works well too.

```
        foreach (byte b in data) {
            sBuilder.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        }
```